# CTRL+C not copying to clipboard after I set ownership of clipboard to StringSelection

Tags: java, clipboard, copy-paste

I use StringSelection and clipbaord methods to paste a string.

```
StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("myString");

    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
```

This gives ownership of the clipboard to selection. I then use the robot to paste the contents which works, but later when I use the robot to try to copy selected text on my screen, by simulating CTRL+C, it seems to fail. I then set a string to the contents of the clipboard and I get "mystring".

```
//Control+c
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyType(KeyEvent.VK_C);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

robot.delay(3000);

//save clipboard into string
String newString = "";
    try {
      newString = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    } catch (HeadlessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 

System.err.println(newString);//prints "myString"
```

I think this may be caused by the second argument of the setContents method of class clipboard in which ownership of the clipboard was given to selection. I don't know how to reset the ownership of clipboard. Java docs say that the lostOwnership method "will be called when another application or another object within this application asserts ownership of the clipboard.", so I don't think that it's because it won't release ownership.

Manually using ctrl+c also fails to copy to clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

First, I thought there was a delay between setting clipboard data and having the data available to other applications. In fact, there is a small delay, and setting a Thread.sleep before getting the contents helped me... but not in all cases. It worked randomly since then.

Then, I coded an application to do system.out.println() of the clipboard (as seem by the java program) continuously... but no matter how many times I did CTRL+C, it only shows the old value (the one when the program has been started). But I am sure the system got my CTRL+C, because at the same time java says there is only old data, windows clipboard viewer and a CTRL+V shows the data I just copied. So, it seems only java can't get the update.

Then, I moved the code to another thread outside the user interface thread, and the problem seems to have stopped. I think there is something that keeps receiving the changes in clipboard, but with the user interface thread busy, even with sleeps, those changes are not received.

So, try to put your code in another thread that is launched from the main thread.